# "Press key to play again" Snake project in C

Tags: c

Hi im making snake game and its almost done but i want to add play again button that restarts the game and i dont know how Any ideas?

Main file:

```
#include "SourceCode&Setup.h" //Game source code
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>


void main()
{

    setup();
    while(GameOver!=1)
    {
        DrawBorder();
        Input();
        Movement();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: what happens if you call `setup()` again? Does this reset your gamestate? You somehow need a function to reset your game state. If you use a struct for your game state, you can duplicate it before actually starting the game and then reuse it later.

Comment: Move the entire content of `main` to a new function `game`. Put a loop in `main` that calls `game` and asks if you want to play again. Depending what `setup` does, you may or may not have to `free` resources after each game. You might need to split `setup` into two functions: things that need to be done once only (such as `srand()`) and things that need to be done every game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your game logic in a `do-while` loop:

```
int main( void )
{
  do
  {
    setup();
    while(GameOver!=1)
    {
        DrawBorder();
        Input();
        Movement();
    }
  } while ( playAnotherGame() );
}
```

where `playAnotherGame()` is something like:

```
#include <ctype.h>
...
int playAnotherGame( void )
{
  fputs( "Play another game? [Y/N]: ", stdout );
  int c;

  /**
   * Read individual characters from standard input until 
   * we see a non-whitespace character
   */
  while ( isspace( c = getchar() ) )
    ;      

  /**
   * Return true if the input character is 'Y' or 'y',
   * false otherwise.
   */
  return tolower( c ) == 'y';
}
```

Some notes:

- There are two standard signatures for `main`:

  ```
  int main( void )
  ```

  and

  ```
  int main( int argc, char **argv )
  ```

  (or equivalent).  If your code doesn't take command-line parameters, use the first form.

  Unless your implementation *explicitly* documents `void main()` as a valid signature, using it will invoke *undefined behavior* - your code may work as expected, it may crash outright, or anything in between.

  `.h` files should only include macro definitions, type definitions, function *declarations*, etc.  They should not contain any function *definitions* or statements.  Put your implementation code in separate `.c` files that are compiled separately and linked.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply put your gameplay into a `do {} while()` loop:

```c
#include "SourceCode&Setup.h" //Game source code
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    char again;
    do 
    {
        setup();
        while(GameOver!=1)
        {
            DrawBorder();
            Input();
            Movement();
        }

        printf("Play again (y/n)?\n");
        int ret = scanf(" %c", &again);
        if (ret != 1)
          again = 'n';  // don't play again in case of error.
        
    } while (tolower(again)=='y');    
}
```

Depending on what `setup` does, you may need to adjust it to be able to be called multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

On a high level I would suggest the following:

1. Create a `initializeGame()` function that sets all variables used during the game to its default. For example setting the score to 0
2. Use `getchar()` to wait for a keypress after finishing the game. This pauses the program until the user presses a key in the console. If the input char is `'n'` then `exit()`
3. In your `main()` function: Create another while(true) loop that resets the game state after every play

Answer (score 0):

```
LABEL:
while(GameOver!=1)
{
    DrawBorder();
    Input();
    Movement();
    printf("Press one to play again:");
    scanf("%c", &x);
    if(x==1)
    {
       goto LABEL;
    }
    else
        break; 
}
```

Comment: try this might work if this does not work try to add "LABLE" inside the loop i've been always doing that

Comment: this looks much like C++ and not like C

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your wish to help is appreciated. Unfortunately, you should improve your answer a bit: 1) Using `goto` just to implement a loop should be avoided. There are loops that do the same. 2) The question is about C, not C++. 3) Generally, code-only-answers a discouraged. Explain what the code does.

Comment: It works for both i guess

Comment: Not really. `cin` and `cout` will not work for C.

Comment: @Addy You cannot access cout (from the C++ stdlib) in C. You can only access C libraries in C++, not the other way around

Comment: ok my bad i was talking about jump statement. in this code program will be in loop until the user decides to exit

Comment: The biggest problem I have with this code is that the indentations make the code extremely difficult to follow. The issue with using `goto` is at least minimized with proper indentations in this case. I'll go ahead and fix it for you this time, but please take more time into properly formatting your answers from now on.

Comment: Of course, it's still not great because it doesn't show x being declared or the containing scope.